# Determining maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over an invariant ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, invariant-theory, cohen-macaulay

Suppose that $G$ is a finite small (i.e. reflection-free) subgroup of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ acting on $S := \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Set $R := S^G$. By 5.20 Corollary of [this](http://www.math.unl.edu/~rwiegand1/BOOK.pdf), the maximal Cohen Macaulay modules of $R$ are in bijection with the irreps of $G$ and are given by $M_j := (S \otimes_\mathbb{C} V_j)^G$, where $V_j$ is the $j$th irrep. If $V_j$ is one dimensional with corresponding character $\chi_j$, then $M_j$ is isomorphic to
\begin{align*}
\{ f \in S \mid g \cdot f = \chi_j(g)^{-1} f \text{ for all } g \in G \}.
\end{align*}
Is there a similar description of the maximal Cohen-Macaulay module $M_j$ when $V_j$ has dimension 2 or greater? Preferably one which only relies on knowing the character, and not requiring one to construct the corresponding representation explicitly.

Comment: Just to fix notation: *small* here is *a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is small if it does not contain any element with codimension one fixed space*.

Comment: Why do you expect something similar to the linear case for $(S \otimes V_j)^G$? You could, of course, use the idempotent corresponding to the character of $V_j$ to write this without mentioning the representation at all: you are looking at occurences of $V_j^*$ in $S$.

Comment: I suppose my confusion stems from the fact that I'm not sure how I'm supposed to view $(S \otimes V_j)^G$ as an $R$-submodule of $S$ (with reference to 5.20 Corollary again). Is there some obvious way to view $(S \otimes V_j)^G$ inside of $S$ that I'm missing? Possibly using the idempotent, as you mentioned.